# Is a domain service used to figure out a value (could be object, list etc) that is not an instance variable of an entity/value?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

I was reading this article recently: http://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2016/09/08/domain-services-vs-application-services/

The writer recommends a class like this:

```
public sealed class AtmService // Domain service
{
    public void WithdrawMoney(Atm atm, decimal amount)
    {
        if (!atm.CanDispenseMoney(amount))
            return;
        decimal amountWithCommission = atm.CalculateAmountWithCommission(amount);
        Result result = _paymentGateway.ChargePayment(amountWithCommission);
        if (result.IsFailure)
            return;
        atm.DispenseMoney(amount);
    }
}
```

Why doesn't the WithdrawMoney method go in the ATM class rather than the ATMService class? Surely this is almost as bad as putting all the domain logic in the application service?

Q1) Is it bad practice to use a domain object A (or list of domain  object A's into domain object B when domain object A (or list of domain object A) is not an instance variable of domain object B? For example:

```
public class Customer
{
   bool valuedCustomer=false;

   public void IsValuedCustomer (List<Order> orders)
   {
      if (orders.Count > 100)
      {
           //Do some more logic here e.g. look how much they have spent etc
           valuedCustomer = true;
      }
   }
}
```

Here the Orders List is passed to the Cutomer class so that it can be determined if they are a valued customer.

Q2) Is a domain service just used to figure out a value (could be object, list etc) that is not an instance variable of an entity/value?

**Update**

Following on from Ewans answer.  Say I had a class like this:

```
public class Customer
    {
       List<Offer> offers = List<Offer>(); //this is the offers the customer is entitled to e.g. two offers out of ten.

       public void AssignOffers (List<Offer> offers)
       {
          //All available offers (say 100) are passed to this method
          //There is logic here to figure out what offers the person is   entitled to (this could be a LINQ query).  If the person is entitled to an offer then add it to the instance variable list
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

That is an odd example. I think the key thing about it, and the reason is it a service, is the use of _paymentGateway.

In my view Domain services are used when you have an operation which crosses Bounded Contexts.

You have your ATM aggregate root, with Banks and whatever and a PaymentGateway with Payments and such.

You don't want to combine these into one giant agregate/bounded context but you do have an operation that requires objects from both. You need some object in which to bundle up the domain crossing logic, so you invent an 'ATMService' and put it in there.

Its not a domain object in its own right because it doesnt have data, just methods.

Like you say though it is odd naming to have a service and an object both called ATM and its not clear why PaymentGateway would be in a different bounded context to ATM

Comment: Thanks.  +1 for "Domain services are used when you have an operation which crosses Bounded Contexts.".  Do you have any links where this is quoted as normal practice?

Comment: Do you ever use Domain Services inside the same bounded context? Is it acceptable to pass one domain object to another domain object (as a method parameter - note that the parameter being passed is not an instance variable of the class containing the method).

Comment: Well my view is that DDD doesn't work in a distributed system, eg webapps, unless you follow an ADM style approach, passing Domain Structs for want of a better term between services. But thats a bit beyond the scope of your question

Comment: I am not against ADMs at all - they are reasonable for some systems.  My question is whether it is "acceptable" for one domain object to be dependant on another when there is no instance variable.

Comment: I think, classically, no. Because you will have crossed a bounded context. Hence the need for services. But then you do sometimes have data transfer objects in DDD. so you would be deciding on when your dto is 'just a dto' and when its a 'domain object' which is a bit fuzzy. with full ADM at one end and 'No Domain Services at all' at the other

Comment: Thanks. However, a bounded context can contain more than one aggregate root.  I am talking about injecting one aggregate root into another aggregate root.

Comment: Given that crossing BC and combining AR are both things to be avoided you have quite a narrow line to walk.

Comment: Please would you look at my method: Customer.IsValuedCustomer().  Is it acceptable to pass a list of objects here or should this be in a domain service? Customer is the aggregate root and order is an aggregate of that aggregate root.  Same bounded context.

Answer (score 0):

re: IsValuedCustomer(List orders)

This is a 'bad' method because either:

- Order should be part of the Customer Aggregate Root. In which case you don't need to pass the orders in.
- OrderCollection is a DomainObject in which case you can have OrderCollection.IsValuedCustomerId(string customerId)
- Customer is a DomainService, in which case it shouldn't have customer data and the naming is odd.

Having said that though, If you were taking an ADM approach where Order was simply a struct or data transfer object. Having a ICustomerValuationService.ValueCustomerFromOrders() could well be a good approach.

In this case Order is your domain object and Customer is a Domain Service

However, this wouldn't be 'classic' DDD (for want of a better term) in my opinion. Which I think assumes you are programming a monolith style OOP app where everything is held in memory, and thus you don't need to pass data objects around.

Comment: Thanks.  Could you have a look at my update (I have written another class to try and explain my problem).

Comment: your edit doesnt really change anything. if a customer has orders then they should be part of the same agregate

Comment: They are part of the same aggregate in the edit, aren't they? i.e. Offer is an instance variable of customer.  In the edited version; I am talking about Customer and Offer rather than Customer and Order.  Perhaps I did not make that clear? I am asking if it is "bad" to inject a list of offers into customer - then the Customer class figures out what offers the customer is entitled to (using the AssignOffers method).

Comment: if you have Customer.Offers as part of the customer aggregate then there should be no need to inject it with a method

Comment: Thanks.  I inject all offers into the AssignOffers method.  AssignOffers then figures out what offers the customer is entitled to.  Does that make sense?

Comment: I can't just inject all the offers.  I have to figure out what offers the customer is entitled to somewhere.  That is what I am trying to figure out.

Comment: thats not really the question you asked though

Comment: Fair enough.  I would be grateful if you would comment on it though - questions lead to other questions.  I did actually try asking the question that lead from this question here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/354518/should-this-code-be-in-a-domain-service, however it was put on hold.